# Magnolia cms: resources module proper usage

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia

I am learning magnolia cms. I am trying to use the resources module. I have actually 2 problems.

1. Cannot upload a bunch of files. I have a few files, but in some time I will have to upload some more. Modules import feature wants me to upload an xml file. But I don't know how to generate it properly. Tried to import through JCR, but after that I can't see those files in resources app. Tried to configure the module to search files in file system: I set fileSystemLoader to class info.magnolia.module.resources.loaders.FileSystemResourceLoader and set some path. It did not work for me too. Maybe I just don't understand at what time should be activated files upload feature. At the application start up time it did not work.
2. How to properly use these resources in my template? What ftl tag should I use?

I don't use STK module.

Thanks for your patience if you decide to help me.

Magnolia version: 5.2 CE

JDK iced tea: 1.7.0_51

OS: Linux/OpenSUSE 12.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used previously (on 4.5.x) script below to perform the task via groovy module. It should work on 5.2 as well.

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES
import info.magnolia.jcr.util.NodeUtil
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils
import info.magnolia.cms.util.ContentUtil

class Globals {
 static def folderName = '//some/folder/in/filesystem/on/server'
}

def loadImageFolder() {
 session = ctx.getJCRSession("resources")
 parentFolder = session.getNode("/templating-kit/jelinek-image/obrazky-produkty")

 new File(Globals.folderName).eachFileRecurse(FILES) {

  name = it.name
  // set file name
  extension = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(name, '.')
  name = StringUtils.substringBeforeLast(name, '.')

  // persist
  resource = NodeUtil.createPath(parentFolder,name , "mgnl:content")
  // persistResource
  resource.setProperty("mgnl:template", "resources:binary")
  resource.setProperty("extension", extension)

  binary = resource.addNode("binary", "mgnl:resource")
  binary.setProperty("jcr:data", new FileInputStream(it.absolutePath))
  binary.setProperty("extension", extension)
  binary.setProperty("fileName", name)
  binary.setProperty("jcr:mimeType", "image/"+extension)
  binary.setProperty("size", it.length())

 }
 session.save()
}

loadImageFolder() 
return 'done'
```

Comment: Thank you. By now I've learned to store these files in the module. I think it is good solution since the page template is being stored at the module too. I will try this script later.

Comment: And what is the best way to use these resources in the template. Is there some api that resolves context path and so on? I mean magnolia api. I ve seen some good feature in gsp that is checking if the resource exists before path resolution.

Comment: ${cmsfn.link(yourResource)} should give you the link either relative or absolute including the context path. All methods of TemplatingFunctions are exposed via cmsfn http://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/sites/magnolia.public.sites/ref/5.2.2/apidocs/index.html?info/magnolia/templating/functions/TemplatingFunctions.html